# Can't get the jQuery dialog to popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the jQuery dialog box to popup up after pressing the "upvote" link here: http://www.problemio.com

(I was working from this example, and then modified it since it didn't work for me: http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/ )

Here is the jQuery code I have so far which doesn't work :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   var $dialog = $('.dialog')
           .dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               title: 'Basic Dialog'
           });   

    $('.vote_up').click(function() 
    {        
        problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");

        var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&vote=+';

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/problems/vote.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data)
                {           
                    // ? :)
                    alert (data);   
                },
                error : function(data) 
                {
                    //alert("ajax error, json: " + data.responseText);
                    errorMessage = data.responseText;

                    if ( errorMessage == "not_logged_in" )
                    {
                        alert ("errr");

                        // Try to create the popup that asks user to log in.
                        //$(this).dialog();
                        //$(".dialog").dialog();
                        $dialog.dialog('open');
                        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert ("not");
                    }

                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });


        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;
    });

    $('.vote_down').click(function() 
    {
        alert("down");

        problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");

        var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&vote=-';        

        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;
    });    
});
</script>
```

Above this code I have another jQuery function that also has a documentOnready check.  Would that matter? Should I make the dialog box code global? If so, how do I do that?

In any case, how can I get the dialog box to open for me with the setup I have now?

Thanks!!

Changed my jQuery imports to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.16/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" />
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. Does the `alert("errr");` alert show?

Comment: First just check and make sure your dialog pops up by doing the following right after initializing the dialog, `$dialog.dialog('open');`. After that you can diagnose further if the ajax response is the problem.

Comment: @BNL yes that alert does show up. The error I am getting is about the dialog object. And other people suggested some imports which I added to my question, which are also giving errors :)

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder no it wasn't happening because I had errors in the declaration. I changed my original question to show my imports which are giving errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this (at the top within your `$(document).ready()`):

```
   var $dialog = $('.dialog')
           .dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               title: 'Basic Dialog'
           });
```

to

```
   var $dialog = $('.dialog');
   $dialog.dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               title: 'Basic Dialog'
           });
```

And it is okay to have multiple `$(document).ready()`, they all should run once the dom is loaded

Comment: just made that change and still get the same error. What imports should I have? The other person's answer mentions some extra library imports which need to be made.

Comment: Yeah, my guess was wrong. It should work without the correction I suggested (Here is the example - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/zqStS/ ). You could try adding this into the head on the page like what @PirateKitten suggested - `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" />`

Comment: it is complaining about that reference: GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.16/jquery.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the [jQuery UI script](http://jqueryui.com/download) on your page. That's what includes the [dialog plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Currently you are only referencing jQuery 1.6.4 in your HTML.

Comment: @PirateKitten what do you mean by include the jquery ui script? I have this code in the header: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script> - is that what you mean?

Comment: That's just the jQuery script. jQueryUI is an additional script which brings in UI functionality and you also need to include that. [This page](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started) should tell you all you need to know about it.

Comment: @PirateKitten could you please show me the snippet that needs to be added? I am a bit confused.  I thought nothing more had to be added than the general jQuery import.

Comment: @PirateKittn I see there under the widgets->dialog -- is that what I need?

Comment: Did you read that page I just linked to? There's even a section marked "Basic overview: using jQuery UI on a web page". You **do** need to add a script reference, jQuery alone isn't enough.

Comment: @PirateKitten the other person answering is suggesting just importing this: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" /> -- I get an error though. Confused which suggestion I should do.  Maybe I don't need a custom jQuery import?

Comment: You haven't copied what @Floyd Pink wrote for you correctly. Are you understanding what the issue is here or are you just wanting to code by copy-and-paste?